# Not apply .po files for module in Orchard CMS

Tags: localization, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.10, po-file

I install Orchard CMS 1.10 and take russian translate from https://crowdin.com/project/orchard-cms and unpack to Orchard.Web. When i added and enabled ru-Ru localization all work good for razor views. But for module isn't. For example i try change validate message for required fields in Orchard.DynamicForms, but nothing happened when displayed validation message, they still english. Also translate not applied for module list in admin panel.

Comment: If you have specified a `msgctext` in your .po file, a translation will only be applied if it matches this string/file exactly. Try only specifying a `msgid` with the validation message, followed by the `msgstr`. This should work across the entire module.

Comment: @Xceno , I remove msgctext but still does not work.
.po example: https://monosnap.com/file/jFxxKla2jqyq7dNGXAJaeZy5tCO9tb

Comment: @levgen, for me it works like this: I've created a .po file with only these two lines: `msgid "{0} is a required field."` and `msgstr "{0} wird benötigt!"`

Comment: Search for the english message in source code, add breakpoint and step into the `T()` call, then check the value of the  scope` parameter. This is the value that should be used in the `msgctext` line.

Comment: That's true, and the scope of your linked example messages has changed. Leaving away the msgctext is only a shortcut for translating the same message in various places without having to have duplicates. So if you want to have fine grained control over each translation; you should take ViRuSTriNiTys approach

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy, @Xceno, Thank you! The approach with viewing scope is nice! I changed the `msgctext` and it worked.

Comment: @levgen I posted my comment as answer so you can mark your question as answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search for the english message in source code, add breakpoint and step into the `T()` call, then check the value of the `scope` parameter. This is the value that should be used in the `msgctext` line.